# Add the tag "shin-megami-tensei" as a synonym for the tag "smt"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just saw that the tag [smt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smt) was added for the game Shin Megami Tensei, but a tag with the full name of the game ([shin-megami-tensei](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shin-megami-tensei)) doesn't exist. I don't have 5 rep in the tag so I can't suggest a synonym for the tag, but it's obvious that a tag should exist for the full name of the game, and it should be synonymous to the abbreviation tag.

Answer (score 2):

Since there was only one question with the [smt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smt) tag, I just changed that one question to [shin-megami-tensei](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shin-megami-tensei). I don't see a reason to create a synonym unless it becomes a persistent problem where people are using the abbreviated version instead of the full version.

Comment: If someone else knows more about this series than I do, please feel free to make a better re-tag. It looks like this game may have a subtitle...

Comment: The full name of the game is [Shin Megami Tensei: Strange Journey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_Megami_Tensei:_Strange_Journey). all the Shin Megami Tensei games have a subtitle as well. Not sure what the best way to rename the tags would be. Poking around online suggests that MegaTen is a common abbreviation for the game among the fanbase, so a format of [tag:megaten-subtitle] could work.